# Georeferencing GeoTIFF in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I am new to QGIS. I just happened to browse to a tutorial on georeferencing in QGIS and I found it easy and interesting.

I also calibrated the map and saved the points as per WSG84 standard. Now after I closed the software and when I restarted I am unable to see the coordinates when I load the GeoTIFF image.

Why am I not able to load the coordinates?

Comment: what do you mean by "saved the points" did you create a vector points layer as shape file and now you can't see the units?
try set project crs from layer.

Comment: WGS84? Are you trying to georeference the map image using lat/lon coordinates?

Comment: It is also not clear what do you mean with "I am unable to see the coordinates".

Answer (score 3):

The GCP points are saved in a file named < filename >.< fileformat >.points in the same directory.
If you start georeferencing Tool again, these points are loaded again, and you can modify them. It is not possible to save them as a vector layer.